# Determine whether Certain Series is Fourier Series of Some Integrable Function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am told to prove that
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n\log(n)}\,e^{inx}$$
is not a Fourier series of an integrable function, and the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n(\log(n))^2}\,e^{inx}$$
is a Fourier series of an integrable function. I have no idea on both of the problems. For the first one, the only two facts that I know to disprove whether a series is a Fourier series are

1. The Fourier coefficients must be in $\ell_2$ class; 2. The Abel/Cesaro sum must be bounded.

None of these seems to work in this case. For the second one, those one can use Dirichlet test to show pointwise convergence, I have no idea of proving uniform convergence.

Comment: For the second: the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$ converges.

Comment: @ClementC. But that doesn't guarantee that the limit function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Jerry No -- just was about your sentence "I have no idea of proving uniform convergence."

Comment: @Zacky What do you mean by integral of RHS? There is no idea what $f$ should be, and the sum at the LHS just converges.

Comment: @Jerry: integrability in what sense? Both are square integrable trigonometric series (in the sense of Lebesgue). The first because $\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{1}{n^2\log^2}<\infty$ ; the second because $\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{1}{n^2\log^4}<\infty$. Being then both in $L_2(\mathbb{S}^2)$, then the are in $L_1(\mathbb{S}^1)$